# Matlab/Octave Pie Chart Categorization

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Do you guys know how I can create a pie chart where if a data point is greater than or is less than a value, it is categorized as increase or decrease on the pie chart. If so, how?
for example, if I ran this code:

```
a = 0.4004990132;
b = 1.226695443;
c = 0.01709;
r(1) = 1.3975;
for t = 2:25
    r(t) = r(t-1)+a*(b-r(t-1))+c*randn;
end
```

Could I make it so it creates a pie chart where when r is greater than the `r(1)` it gets marked as increase and when it is lower, as decrease. So that the pie chart will be separated by the % of time that there was an increase vs. decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the example in your question 100% of the values in `r(2:end)` are greater than `r(1)`, so I generated some other sample data to illustrate the solution to what I think you have been asking:

```
r1 = 0.3; % threshold level
r = rand(25,1); % uniform random values between 0..1
rup = sum(r>r1); % count how many values greater than r1
rdown = sum(r<r1); % count how many values smaller than r1
% plot the precentage as a pie chart:
pie([rup rdown],{sprintf('%2.0f%% Increase',rup/25*100),...
    sprintf('%2.0f%% Decrease',rdown/25*100)})
```

this will create:
[image: % pie]

or something like it, since the data is random.